# Ubuntu installation choosing partition

Tags: partitioning, system-installation

I am installing Ubuntu, I saw some guides but still nothing.

I understood that I have to choose the partition ntfs, the biggest one and change it, choose the dimension and now how to use the partition. There are a lot of options I do not know which one to choose and how to proceed.

I have Windows and I want to install Ubuntu with just 20 gb more less.

[image: screenshot1]
[image: screenshot2]

Answer (score 0):

I agree with starkus.

GParted is an excellent tool for partition managing.

If you feel intimidated you can resize the disk from your Windows installation. Use [this](https://www.howtogeek.com/101862/how-to-manage-partitions-on-windows-without-downloading-any-other-software/) as guide.

Windows partition managing tool is more limited than GParted but it should be enough to free up 20GB.

After that done, next time you boot into Ubuntu LiveCD you'll see free unpartitioned space, this is where you would choose to install ubuntu. Pick "Ext4" as you partition format.
If you are low on ram, say less than 8Gb, I would also leave some space for swap partition.